# Can we smoothly embed $\mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{S}^1$ or $\mathbb{RP}^2 \times \mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Tags: differential-topology

I've been thinking a little bit about smooth embeddings recently.  In particular, I was wondering:

> Do the $3$-manifolds $\mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{S}^1$ and $\mathbb{RP}^2 \times \mathbb{R}$ embed smoothly into $\mathbb{R}^4$?

As with most of the questions I ask on this site, I ask entirely out of curiosity, and largely because I have no idea how to even begin.

Further question: If either of the above has a positive answer, could we (more generally) embed $\Sigma^2 \times \mathbb{S}^1$ or $M^2 \times \mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}^4$, where $\Sigma^2$, $M^2$ are compact (orientable, non-orientable, resp.) smooth surfaces.

Note: I'm aware that the $3$-manifolds $\Sigma^2 \times \mathbb{S}^1$ can be immersed into $\mathbb{R}^4$ and embedded into $\mathbb{R}^5$.

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{RP}^2\times\mathbb{R}$ is not compact.

Comment: Ugh, thank you, not sure why I wrote that.  I'll edit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If $\Sigma^2$ is a compact orientable surface, then $\Sigma^2\times\mathbb{S}^1$ can be smoothly embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$.  The trick is simple: first embed $\Sigma^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^4$, and let $T$ be a [tubular neighborhood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tubular_neighborhood) of the surface.  Then the closure of $T$ is isomorphic to $\Sigma^2\times\mathbb{D^2}$, and the boundary of $T$ is isomorphic to $\Sigma^2\times\mathbb{S}^1$.  Note that $\Sigma^2\times\mathbb{R}$ also embeds in $\mathbb{R}^4$, since it is a submanifold of $\Sigma^2\times\mathbb{S}^1$.

No closed, non-orientable 3-manifold can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$, for the same reason that no closed, non-orientable surface can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  (If there were such an embedding, then the "inward-pointing" normals could be used to define an orientation of the manifold.)  In particular, if $M^2$ is a compact, non-orientable surface, then $M^2\times\mathbb{S}^1$ cannot be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

The case $M^2\times\mathbb{R}$ for $M^2$ a non-orientable surface is covered briefly in [this paper](http://www.pef.uni-lj.si/dusanr/clanki/2001/AhReSk01.pdf) (near the top of the fourth page).  In particular:

- If $M^2$ has odd Euler characteristic (such as the projective plane), then $M^2\times\mathbb{R}$ cannot embed in $\mathbb{R}^4$.  (This is related to, but does not follow from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41812/no-hypersurface-with-odd-euler-characteristic).)  The paper linked to above gives the following argument for this:

  > Although $M^2$ is not orientable, the normal Euler class $\bar{e}(M^2)\in\mathbb{Z}$ of an *embedding* $M^2\subset\mathbb{R}^4$ is well-defined and $\bar{e}(M^2) = 2\,\chi(M^2)\;\mathrm{mod}\;4$ [several citations given].  Hence the normal bundle of an embedding $M^2\subset\mathbb{R}^4$ has no cross-sections.
- If $M^2$ has even Euler characteristic, then $M^2\times\mathbb{R}$ can be smoothly embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$.  This should be clear for the Klein bottle—the standard immersion of the Klein bottle $K$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be "thickened" to give an immersion of $K\times\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$, which can then be modified slightly to give an embedding into $\mathbb{R}^4$.  The same argument works for the other surfaces with even Euler characteristic, since each of them is simply a Klein bottle with handles attached.

Comment: At the end of the first bullet point, I assume you mean $\mathbb{R}^4$, not $S^4$. I appreciate, by the way, that you discussed the case of $M^2 \times \mathbb{S}^1$ although I did not explicitly ask for it. As you probably guessed, I was in fact thinking more generally about $3$-manifolds that split as products of $1$- and $2$-manifolds :-)

Comment: @JesseMadnick Actually, I don't think my argument there was correct.  The answer to the question I linked to only applies in the case that the submanifold is closed.  I have replaced this with a quote of the more technical argument given in the paper.

Comment: The case of when a 2-manifold cross an interval embeds into $\mathbb R^4$ was first handled (and completely answered) by Hassler Whitney in his paper: "On the topology of differentiable manifolds" Lectures in topology, U.Michigan Press, 1941.

Comment: In your first paragraph, are you claiming that any embedding of $\Sigma$ into $\mathbb{R}^4$ extends to an embedding of $\Sigma \times S^1$?    Or, more specifically, are you claiming that the normal bundle of $\Sigma$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ is independent of embedding?  (I agree that if we embed $\Sigma$ into $\mathbb{R}^3 $ in the usual way and then embed $\mathbb{R}^3$ into $\mathbb{R^4}$ in the usual way, that the normal bundle of $\Sigma is trivial - and that this is enough to answer the OP's question.  It is just not clear to me what happens for an arbitrary embedding.)

Comment: @JasonDeVito The normal bundle to a compact, orientable $n$-manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ or $\mathbb{R}^{n+2}$ is always trivial.  See [W. Massey, On the Normal Bundle of a Sphere Imbedded in Euclidean Space. _Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society_ **10.6** (1959), 959-964](https://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2033630).  See also [this MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/237384/is-the-normal-bundle-of-a-torus-trivial).

Comment: @Jim: Well, I learned something today.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Any product of spheres embeds in codimension $1$. That's a nice exercise with the Tubular Neighborhood Theorem. I'm not sure yet about the second.