# $S^1\times S^2$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, compact-manifolds

It's easy to embed $S^1\times S^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^5$, since $S^1\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and $S^2\subset\mathbb{R}^3$, but $S^1\times S^2$ lives also in $\mathbb{R}^4$. How can we write the embedding map $S^1\times S^2\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: I don’t have a concrete embedding at hand, but I would try to adapt the usual embedding of the torus $\Bbb S^1\times \Bbb S^1 \subseteq \Bbb R^3$…

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429614.

Comment: Consider any embedding $S^1\to \bf R^4$, let $C$ the image. Then the boundary of a tubular neigbourhood of C is $S^1\times S^2$, as the normal bundle is trivial (orientable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an explicit construction: $$(x,y,a,b,c)\mapsto ((2+x)a, (2+x)b, (2+x)c, y)$$
where $x^2+y^2=a^2+b^2+c^2=1$. Note that given

$(\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta)$ in the image, we can recover $x=\frac{\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2+\delta^2-5}{4}$, and hence $a,b,c$.

Comment: Nice idea, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't check it's an immersion but it's just computation.